# Xamarin image from REST

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I would like to make an app in Xamarin using C# and Visual Studio.

I have a REST api that returns a JSON like this:

```
{"online_ID":"1490","online_title":"H\u00f4tel Le Cleebourg","picture_filename":"http://example.com/images/W253H19069d1a539017504338797a27241f45207.jpg"}
```

I would like to show that image in an ImageView. Does anybody know if that is possible and how ?

Thanks

Comment: I found it in another thread from stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple and efficient way of doing it.

Step 1: Add this component to your project. https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/urlimageviewhelper

Step 2 : Add this code where you want to bind the image.

```
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (imageView, "http://example.com/image.png");
```

Note: imageview is where you would want your image to be binded. This component also handles lazy loading and caching of image.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
     Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

     using (var webClient = new WebClient())
     {
          var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
          if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
          {
               imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
          }
     }

     return imageBitmap;
}

var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("http://xamarin.com/resources/design/home/devices.png");
imagen.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```